# Can’t debug all projects inside my solution because PDB doesn’t load correctly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I have several projects inside my solution, a web presentation layer, that consume data from some webservices, I can debug the presentation layer, but can't stop the debugger on the webservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several times in my life as .NET Developer I have had some issue with loading PDB’s files. Each time I have had this kind of problem, I've wasted a lot of time trying to found a solution but usually I can’t find the solution easily because this happens not for an obvious reason.
The common solutions many times I read were:

•   Reset Visual Studio Settings
•   Removed all files in every \Temporary ASP.NET Files Folder Cleanup the project
•   Create a new solution and added all the projects to this new solution
•   Delete the solution suo file
•   Create a new ASP.NET Web Application to test if it is a VS-installation issue
•   Reboot the machine
•   Repaired the vs.net installation
•   IISReset
•   Remove the Web App from IIS

But mostly times, this solution didn't work. The most common solutions worked for me was:

1. Clean Solution.
2. Check all projects in the solution have the same .NET Framework version and are running in debug mode.
3. This was the most complicated to discover I found until today, was because the project load, makes reference to some webservices, and the webservices, were working on the IIS Express, so the presentation layer always works fine but the webservice project doesn't load the PDB files. 
   The solution was:

a.  Solution --> Properties Select multiple startup projects select Start action on the projects you need to debug.
b.  Clean up the solution and rebuild it.

Hope this helps someone, and if you found another solution for this kind of problem, please let a comment.

Comment: Since this issue has been resolved, you could mark it as the answer.